# Adding patch clusters in a landscape

Tags: netlogo

I would like to add forest patches in a landscape. To be more precise, the idea is to add patch clusters like "Patch Clusters" example. Contrary to this example, I want to randomly distribute some patch clusters with the same color and not several clusters that fill entirely the landscape. This is a beginning of code :

```
to create-forests 
repeat 30 [
ask one-of patches [ 
set pcolor green
ask neighbors [ set pcolor green] ] ]
end
```

With this code, the clusters look like squares and not clusters like "Patch Clusters" example. How can I add forest patch clusters in my landscape ?

Thank you for your help
Have a good day
Marine

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20336364/86485

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
to create-forests
  ask n-of 10 patches [ set pcolor green ]
  repeat 6 [
    ask patches with [pcolor = green] [
      ask one-of neighbors4 [ set pcolor green ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

The results look like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A fast solution could be using patch-at-heading-and-distance function.

```
to create-forests 

  ask patches[set pcolor black]
  repeat 5 
  [
    ask one-of patches
    [ 
      set pcolor green
      repeat 20
      [
        let a random 360
        let b random 2
        ask patch-at-heading-and-distance a b 
        [ 
          ask neighbors4 [ set pcolor green]
          set pcolor green 
        ]
      ]
    ] 
  ]
end
```

With this function you can move to another patch neighbor. Playing with the range of the random values of a (angle), b (distance) and the number of times that is repeated this part of code, can be achieved different forest densities.

With neighbors 4 we try to fill possible black patches inside the forest, (Note that the success of this trick will depend of the forest size)

A more sophisticated option could be:

```
to create-forests2

  ask patches[set pcolor black]
  repeat 5
  [
    ask one-of patches
    [ 
      let size_f (random 2) + 1
      let border 2

      let big_area [list pxcor pycor] of patches with [abs pxcor <= size_f + border and abs pycor <= size_f + border]   
      let forested [list pxcor pycor] of patches with [abs pxcor <= size_f + random border and abs pycor <= size_f + random border]   

      ask patches at-points forested[set pcolor green]
      ask patches at-points big_area with[pcolor != green]
      [ if count(neighbors with [pcolor = green]) > 6 [ set pcolor green ] ]
    ] 
  ]
end
```

With the help of a list are identified the patches surrounded in 6/8 of forest, thus are converted to forest also

Comment: With this code, there is sometimes one black patch within a cluster of green patches (i.e. at center of a cluster). Is it possible to have clusters only composed of green patches ?