# How to create cluster patches that do not overlap between them

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create habitat clusters (e.g. forest patches as in the subject of Marine : [Adding patch clusters in a landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326781/adding-patch-clusters-in-a-landscape)) by controlling the size of clusters and the number of clusters ? For example, I used the code of "plant-migration" :

```
 to create-forests
 ask n-of forest-number patches
[
 set pcolor green 
]
ask patches with [pcolor = green]
[
 let a self
 let b max list 1 round(random-normal mean-forest-area (mean-forest-area * coef-forest-area))
 ask patches with [distance a <= b]
 [ 
   set pcolor green ]
 ]
end
```

How can I create cluster patches that do not overlap between them ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code:

```
to make-cluster
  loop [
    let cluster [patches in-radius (2 + random-float 2)] of one-of patches
    if all? (patch-set [neighbors] of cluster) [pcolor = black] [
       ask cluster [ set pcolor green ]
       stop
    ]
  ]
end
```

If I run it like this:

```
clear-all repeat 15 [ make-cluster ]
```

I get this:

[image]

Note that none of the clusters touch or overlap.

Comment: By using this code in a large spatial extent (e.g 1000 x 1000 patches), why do all green patches take a circular shape ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How could the world size make a difference?

Comment: I used patch size = 1 pixel. Maybe this size is too small to well perceive variability in patch shape. Even if I modify the parameter "2 + random-float 2" in the code, green patches look like circles. Is it possible to increase "cutting-out" patches in order to have different patch shapes that are visible at large spatial scale ? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hmm... still not understanding. Isn't circles exactly what you would expect `in-radius` to produce? Maybe ask a new question with images showing what you're getting and what you want it to look like instead?

Comment: Is it possible to have green patch clusters as shown in the figure with the same area (i.e. same patch number in cluster) ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Instead of `in-radius (2 + random-float 2)`, use a fixed radius. If you want the same area but different shapes, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20997901/86485

Comment: Thanks Seth ! In fact, I prefer to have symmetrical clusters with different shapes as shown in the figure. If, for example, I want to have clusters of 0.6 km² (i.e. 6000 patches in the cluster), is it possible to build symmetrical clusters of 6000 patches with different shapes ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Seems like a new question.