# NetLogo: patchy forest - keep total area and blob size stable and not overlap

Tags: debugging, netlogo

I realize that my question is just slight modification of questions:

- [Adding patch clusters in a landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326781/adding-patch-clusters-in-a-landscape)

  [How to create cluster patches that do not overlap between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336364/how-to-create-cluster-patches-that-do-not-overlap-between-them)
  and

  [To build patch clusters at large spatial scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121735/to-build-patch-clusters-at-large-spatial-scales)

but I can't modify them to satisfied my needs.

I need to produce a patchy forest landscape. Each setup, the **total area of "green" patches has to be same (20%, 10%... of total count patches) and the size of one blob should be same.** Thus: blob_size = area / number_blobs

I suggest that

```
to create-forests
  clear-all
  ask n-of 1 patches [ set pcolor green ]
  repeat 6 [
    ask one-of patches with [pcolor = green ] [
      ask one-of neighbors4 with [pcolor = black] [ 
        set pcolor green ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

should be the answer, as by `n-of 1 (number_blobs) patches` I create number of blobs needed, and `blob_size` is constrained by `repeat 6 (blob_size)`. However, in my simple example I have an `error ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.` apparently because `one-of patches with [pcolor = green]` has not black neighbors.

Please, how can I include the condition `ask one-of patches with [pcolor = green ] and with min-one of neighbors4 with [pcolor = black]` in my code? 
Or what is the different way to do this? I need to keep my total area of green patches same, and patches size +- same too, the best would be if they will not overlap. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified to make-blob from: [Creating a random shape (blob) of a given area in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997901/creating-a-random-shape-blob-of-a-given-area-in-netlogo)

- my blobs still can overlap but at least total "area" is the same for every run

  ```
  to make-blob
    let total_area 500       ;  how patches I want to turn green
    repeat 5 [               ; number of blobs I want to  have
      let blob-maker nobody
      crt 1 [ set blob-maker self     
         setxy random-xcor random-ycor]  ; set random position of "blob-makers"
      repeat 10 [               ; size of one blob (number of patches of the same color close one to another)
      ask blob-maker [
         ask min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = black ] [ distance myself ] [ set pcolor green ]
    rt random 360
    fd 1
  ]
  ]
  ask blob-maker [ die ]
  ]
  end
  ```

resulting in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
to create-forests
  clear-all
  ask n-of 1 patches [ set pcolor green ]
  repeat 6 [
    ask one-of patches with [pcolor = green and any? neighbors4 with [ pcolor = black ] ] [
      ask one-of neighbors4 with [pcolor = black] [ 
        set pcolor green ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: thank you @BryanHead! Your example produces blobs of different size. I can produce the blobs of same size by just changing it to `ask patches with [pcolor = green and any? neighbors4 with [ pcolor = black ] ] `as you suggested. Please, is there any way how to not let to overlap them? maybe some sort of "halo-effect" among the first "nucleus" patches?